# Apache Camel Ftp consumer concurrency support

Tags: java, ftp, apache-camel

In the official camel documentation it says its does not support concurrency and explain it like below:

> FTP Consumer does not support concurrency.
>
> The FTP consumer (with the same endpoint) does not support concurrency (the backing FTP client is not thread safe).
>
> You can use multiple FTP consumers to poll from different endpoints. It is only **a single endpoint** that does not support concurrent consumers.
>
> The FTP producer does not have this issue, it supports concurrency.

Does "a single endpoint" here means same remote folder or same camel `FtpEndpoint` object? If I make filename part of the endpoint (like below) and make them different then will it be safe to download them concurrently?

```
from("ftp://admin@localhost:21/nolist/?password=admin&stepwise=false&useList=false&fileName=report.txt")
```

Answer (score 1):

Endpoint here means the same endpoint instance created via the `from` definition - so in essence the same `FtpEnpoint` object.

Yes, if you make the filename parameter different it will be safe to download them concurrently. Or use different `antInclude` patterns, that should also be safe.

But even if you used the same filename it should be safe if you use a properly configured `idempotentRepository` and `inProgressRepository` to disallow concurrent consumption of the same file.